# Pass a list through Ajax in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, python-3.x

I have made an Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
              url:'/quespaper/intermediate_table',
              type:'GET',
              processData: false,
              data:{'url_link':url_link_copy,'updated_url_link':er},
               success: function(data){ alert('Urls updated');},
               error:function(error){
                 alert(error);
                 console.log(error);
               }
            });
```

Here,url_link_copy is a list,which is being properly printed at the console and er is the collection of value of all text boxes:

```
var er = $(".form-control.input-sm").val();
```

The mapping to a views.py function is correct,but,in that function,when I print the data,it prints:**None**.

I tried JSON.stringify also:

```
data:JSON.stringify({'url_link':url_link_copy,'updated_url_link':er})
```

But,it also didn't work.

Please suggest what is wrong in this implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share your `views.py` file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Sharma96/08907e199114eb109a80c392b0420646

Comment: You should print the value of `request.GET` in your view. jQuery is probably doing something horrible to the data.

Comment: the data was being printed,just the way of access was not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [getlist()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) function of the get request object.
So instead of

`url_link = request.GET.get('url_link')`

try

`url_link = request.GET.getlist('url_link')`